# Can you chase away the robber if your knight is not active at the beginning of your turn?

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights

Can you use your knight to chase away the robber if it was inactive at the beginning of your turn?

Answer (score 5):

No.

According to the rules,

> A knight may not be activated and then perform an action on the same turn.